# Listing files that match a criteria in R

Tags: r, regex, file-search

I have a series of files. Every file name has two numbers. The first number is the generation number and it can be a number between 0 - 250. The next number is the model number which is between 1 - 450.

Some examples:

```
Generation_Flux_0_Model_10.txt
Generation_Flux_0_Model_5.txt
Generation_Flux_1_Model_20.txt
Generation_Flux_2_Model_17.txt
Generation_Flux_5_Model_9.txt
Generation_Flux_55_Model_5.txt
Generation_Flux_117_Model_2.txt
Generation_Flux_8_Model_23.txt
```

I want to list files only for a specified set of generations. For example, getting the files for generation 1 and 8 should list only:

> Generation_Flux_**1**_Model_20.txt and Generation_Flux_**8**_Model_23.txt.

I wrote the following line which only results in a binary value.

```
reactionFile = list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
generations = c(0, 1, 8)
str_extract(reactionFile,"\\d+")%in%generations
```

> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

1. Is there a way to specify this criteria in the
   list.files(pattern="") parameter?
2. Also which way would be faster to select the only required files?
   Listing all the files in the directory and getting a subset or
   loading only the required files using list.files()?

Comment: For each generation number if it is single digit use a character class like `^Generation_Flux_[81]_Model_\\d+\\.txt$`. If it is more than one single digit like generations `55` and `110` use a group: `^Generation_Flux_(55|110)_Model_\\d+\\.txt$`. For a general solution for both single and multi digit numbers use grouping.

Comment: ... but if you want generations 1 through 50 you should build a pattern for it: `^Generation_Flux_([1-9]|[1-4]\\d|50)_Model_\\d+\\.txt$`

Comment: @revo In R, we could dynamically build an alternation with any set of numbers.

Comment: @revo the first solution works. Second one might be handy if my requirement changes. Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That would be long for `x` through `y` with a long span between but yea dirty and handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
list.files(pattern = "^Generation_Flux_[18]_Model_\\d+\\.txt$")
```

This should match only generations 1 and 8, with any model number.

If you have an arbitrary set of generation numbers, then you may dynamically build an alternation, e.g.

```
getGens <- function(v) {
    pat <- paste0("(", paste0(v, collapse="|"), ")")
    return(pat)
}

gens <- c(1, 50, 100, 150)      # or any values you wish to use
pat <- paste0("^Generation_Flux_", getGens(gens), "_Model_\\d+\\.txt$")
list.files(pattern = pat)
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work for single digits. However it doesn't work for more than one digit numbers e.g. 10, 18 Coz the generation number can vary between 0 - 250.

Comment: I answered to your example, which is for 1 and 8.  Tell me the actual problem and I can update my answer.

Comment: Generation number varies between 0 - 250. I would like to list the files for a specified set of generations e.g. [1, 50, 100, 150], [1, 5, 8] it changes every time.

Comment: @SriniShine Answer updated with an option assuming you have a vector or maybe list of the generation numbers on tap somewhere.

Comment: the solution looks neat. Thanks.